# How to retrieve the all available PIDs on windows in tcl?

Tags: windows, process, tcl, pid

I wanted to know the method for retrieving all available pids in windows through tcl coding. This is I need for killing process based on if it available or not?.
Thanking you.
code:

```
proc stopprogressbar {} {
  variable n_progressWinPid;
  if {[info exists n_progressWinPid]} {
    if {$n_progressWinPid > 0} {
      if {[lsearch [GETALLPIDS] $n_progressWinPid] >= 0} {
        catch {exec [auto_execok taskkill] /PID $n_progressWinPid}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[twapi::get_process_ids](http://twapi.magicsplat.com/process.html#get_process_ids) returns all PIDs on a Windows system. You have to `package require twapi` first.

If you're using ActiveTcl, run `C:\Tcl\bin\teacup.exe install twapi` (or wherever you installed Tcl) in a command prompt to get TWAPI. It may even be included by default in newer ActiveTcl versions, I don't know.

Comment: yep... this is what I was looking for.. And I used the same package.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your goal is to kill a process if exists. How about killing it any way, without checking?

```
package require Tclx;           # For the kill command
catch {kill $n_progressWinPid}; # Kill the process
```

Other commands in the Tclx package which you might find useful:

```
id process;        # Get PID for this process
id process parent; # Get PID for the parent of this process
wait ?many options? pid; # Wait for a process
```

Please look up help for the Tclx package for more information.

Comment: That is true that I want to kill the process ultimately, but in main programm I want to check if pid (n_progressWinPid) exists or not. This is for if that pid does not exists then stop the main process otherwise continue. (main process is not jut single loop)

Comment: @OliveOne Checking if a process exists is best done with looking for the directory `/proc/$thepid` or by running the system program `ps` with the right options (e.g., `exec ps -p $thepid`). Alas, these are all non-portable for historical reasons.